# Can I "offload" printing support to an external host or service when there is no native driver available?

Tags: drivers, printing, print-drivers, printing-software

I have a situation where a particular printer (HP DesignJet 800 plotter) doesn't have a driver for a particular client operating system (Windows 8), and as a result, those users can't print to this device.

Are there solutions available, whether in the form of software that can be installed on an alternate host or perhaps a web-based service, that would effectively allow me offload the printing responsibility from the client to that host or service, where a driver was available?

*Moderators:* I tried to word this question as broadly as possible so that it is not perceived as solving a very particular, specific problem.  I only gave the examples of the client OS and printer type to better plain the problem.

Comment: Why don't you [connect it to the network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-printer-home-network#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: The op said there's no driver available - network or not isn't the issue.